# How to store lat and long from database Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, leaflet

I am try to store Latitude and Longitude from Database FireStore , so it can be retrieved and use for leaflets to display markers on map .

Firebase Service Class

```
export interface PostionsAddress {
  id?: string,
  name: string,
  notes: string,
  lat:any,
  lng:any
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostionServiceService {

  private ideas: Observable<PostionsAddress[]>;
  private ideaCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<PostionsAddress>;


  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.ideaCollection = this.afs.collection<PostionsAddress>('Locations');
    this.ideas = this.ideaCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }

  getIdeas(): Observable<PostionsAddress[]> {
    return this.ideas;
  }



}
```

Here is code for Home page class

```
export class HomePage {

  private $location: Observable<PostionsAddress[]>;

  map: Map;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth,private locationservice:PostionServiceService) {  }


  ionViewDidEnter() { this.loadmap(); }

  loadmap() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map = new Map('map').setView([33.3152, 44.3661], 10);

      tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

      }).addTo(this.map);

       ---- HERE GETTING COORDS FROM DATABASE ------
      this.locationservice.getIdeas().pipe(map(a=>{
        return a.map(a=>{
          let Icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
          });
          L.marker([a.lat,a.lng], {
            icon: Icon
          }).addTo(this.map);
          console.log(a.lat,a.lng)
        })
      })) 

    }, 100);
  }

}
```

The problem is , According my code above in home page class , the markers are not showing on map and there is not error shows in console log . Any idea please why markers are not showing on map according to my code above ?

Comment: Are u getting the data from the database

Comment: Yes , cloud firestore

Comment: What are you getting here `console.log(a.lat,a.lng)`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad nothing show !

Comment: then you are not retrieving the data..

Comment: @PeterHaddad , there is any mistake in my code above ?

Comment: Try after `this.locationservice.getIdeas().pipe(map(a=>{` `console.log(a)` what result do you get? And try to change `return a.map(a=>{` to `return a.map(b=>{` also `a.lat`

Comment: @FalkeDesign , nothing shows in console log ever !

Comment: Then you have to find out why the pipe not gets the data. What do you get with`console.log( this.locationservice.getIdeas())`? Sorry I can't help you more, i never programmed in angular

Comment: As mentioned by falke the data is not being sent, I could suggest tou make sure you get the [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/firestore) on firestore up and just modify needed parts to send and receive the data

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have fixed my problem for why markers are not showing on map ! .

After save data into firestore database , l created `getAllMarkers` method in `Firebase Service Class` to retrieving the data markers collection from database , whereas the `getAllMarkers()` would return all the markers (as an observable).

```
  getAllMarkers() {
    return this.afs.collection("Locations").valueChanges();
  }
```

home.ts file

```
 loadmap() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map = new Map('map').setView([33.3152, 44.3661], 10);

      tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

      }).addTo(this.map);

     ---------- HERE-----------

      this.locationservice.getAllMarkers().subscribe((markers: any) => {
        markers.forEach(singlemarker => {

          let Icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
          });
          L.marker([singlemarker.lat, singlemarker.lng], {
            icon: Icon
          }).addTo(this.map);
          console.log(singlemarker.lat, singlemarker.lng)
        });
      });


    }, 100);
  }
```

Now l have all markers on map